# How to pass the values from Spring controller to JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have Spring controller and I am setting a model value and want to display in my JSP:

```java
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("message", "Programmer Gate");
        return "/test";
    }
}
```

My `test.jsp` code:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    double num = Math.random();
    if (num > 0.95) {
%>
<h2>You'll have a luck day!</h2><p>(<%= num %>)</p>
<%
} else {
%>
<h2>Well, life goes on ... </h2><p>(<%= num %>)</p>
<%
    }
%>
<p>${message}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not seeing the message value as the JSP rendering as follows:

```
Well, life goes on ...
(0.3343913194169942)

${message}
```

How to access the model message variable value in the JSP?

Comment: Add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` at top of your jsp file and see if that works